# Are there limitations on Terraform variable expansion?

Tags: git, variables, reference, terraform, expansion

I am in the process of implementing changes to Terraform code in order to be able to reuse Powershell code by referencing it as functions using Gitref's instead of having repeated blocks of identical code strewn through the codebase. Typical code reuse scenario, nothing new. However, I have been told that Terraform will not do variable expansion at the very beginning of an Apply. I need to pass the Gitref (branch identifier) into Terraform at the beginning of a Gitlab pipeline. Is there a reason this would not work from the very beginning of the Apply?

Comment: Do you have any TF code to show what you are trying to do?

Comment: Not yet.  For now I just want to know if there are any such restrictions.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "Terraform will not do variable expansion at the very beginning of an Apply."?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. The expansion will not work when defining the source of the module to be imported as a gitref import.

Comment: Specifically, I cannot specify a variable as the gitref. It has to be hard coded, and we have to use code to modify the gitrefs en-masse within the pipeline.